# For loop in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am making use of Gridster widgets on webpage.Each widget is having a button on it which changes the color to red of widget after that is clicked(It basically should imply that this widget is selected).Once that button is pressed the parent element(of the button clicked that is a particular widget) gets added to an array as well

The meta information about variables in for loop is as follows

`parentElement`:An array which should have widgets which are highlighted/selected

`currentElement`: The widget which is currently selected or for which the button is pressed

**I have written a for loop and the expected logic of that loop should be as follows**

1. If the array `parentElement` is empty (That is no element in the array) 
   then the element which is clicked `currentElement` should get added in the array
2. If the array `parentElement` is not empty then the element which is clicked `currentElement` should be checked for its presence in the entire `parentElement` array
3. If `currentElement` found then `currentElement` should not be added in `parentElement` else it should be added

**My main aim is to remove the `currentElement` from `parentElement` array if it is already present in the `parentElement` array**

My JS for same is as follows

```
var parentElement = [];

$(document).on("click", ".change-widget-color", function() {
  currentElement = $(this).closest('li');
  $(this).closest('li').toggleClass("red") //Highlighting the element which is selected

  if (parentElement.length === 0) {

    parentElement.push(currentElement);

  } 
  else {
    for (var i = 0; i < parentElement.length; i++) {

      if (JSON.stringify(parentElement[i]) === JSON.stringify(currentElement)) {

        console.log("Element already present");

      } 
      else {

        parentElement.push(currentElement);

      }
    }
  }

});
```

**Overall Expected Output**

My main intention is that before adding `currentElement` in the array `parentElement` it should be checked.If it is present then I should remove that element

I am not able to figure out how I will remove the current element if it is already present.

**The  Problem in my for loop**

The above for loop behaves in a very wierd way.I dont know whats wrong with the logic but when I do console.log it executes both `if` and `else` condition

Any help will be really appreciated

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ocy069ws/)

Comment: I deleted my answer since I was wrong at some point. The for loop goes through the entire array and compares if there are the same element, if false, then add the element to the array and continue the for loop. But as you add an element into the array, the array length increases, and it will compare the current element to the element you just added, so it would always says "Element already present".

Comment: Yeah that was the inherent problem with my loop as well.So is there any way to overcome it ?

Comment: You can follow AnilRedshift's answer, it overcomes the problem.

Comment: But by that answer I am not able to remove the element which is already present.I am not getting how can I include that thing as well

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the array as you loop through it.
So, in one loop, you are adding the `currentElement` to the array. This increments parentElement.length. Thus, you do *another* iteration of the loop where the index points to the currentElement that you just inserted.

EDIT: Also you are calling `JSON.stringify()` on a jquery element, which is not what you want. You should just do a direct compare on the element. Notice the `[0]` part which takes the first DOM element out of jquery.

You should check the array to see if it's unique, and then insert it like so:

```
if (parentElement.every(element => element[0] !== currentElement[0])) {
  parentElement.push(currentElement);
}
```

Comment: Can you just explain that with updating the fiddle

Comment: It will be really helpful to understand that way

Comment: That's not really how stackoverflow works. The code I posted replaces your entire `if/else`

Comment: I tried it by myself following your answer [here](https://jsfiddle.net/thsxcjwo/1/) But how can I remove the element.if it is already present.

Comment: When I check in console.log.It does not adds same element again.

Answer (score 0):

Base on AnilRedshift's answer, you can remove the same element by the following code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".select-element", function() {
    currentElement = $(this).closest('li');
    $(this).closest('li').toggleClass("red") //Highlighting the element which is selected
    if (parentElement.length === 0) {
        parentElement.push(currentElement);
        console.log("Parent Element");
        console.log(parentElement);
    } else {
        // check if the array already has the same element
        if (parentElement.every(element => element[0] !== currentElement[0])) {
            parentElement.push(currentElement);
        }
        else{
            console.log('Element already present')
            // find the index of the existed element
            var index = parentElement.findIndex(x=>x[0] === currentElement[0])
            // remove it
            parentElement.splice(index,1)
        }
        console.log("Final Parent Element");
        console.log(parentElement);
    }   
});
```

Comment: I tried it here https://jsfiddle.net/8o7aupty/ But even when new element is added it says "element already present"

Comment: I tried it here https://jsfiddle.net/qa8dktar/1/ The element which gets removed is not the one which is clicked twice.I clicked 3 elements say A, B, C. and click B again Then A is deselected B and C are present in the array itself

Comment: It always removes the first element in the array